# Is there a way to sum of elements in 2 elements into a new list in c#

Tags: c#, list

I have two different list of the same count am trying to sum up into a new list

```
 List<int> Calculate = new List<int>();
 List<int> new_Quantity= new List<int>();
 List<int> Qty= new List<int>();
```

so let new_Quantity assume has int values of [2,3,4]
and Qty has int values of [2,4,5]. so i want the new list to have calculate [4,7,9]
this is what have used so far

```
For each(var i in new_Quantity)
{
   for each(var j in Qty)
   {
      calculate.add( i + j);
   }
}
```

but it not getting the exact calculation i want as this output is [4,7,9,4,7,9,4,7,9];
so how do i fix this?

Comment: Just use a for loop and `result[i] = list1[i] + list2[i];` or if you want to try Linq check out `Enumerable.Zip`.

Comment: `var third = first.Zip(second, (f, s) => f + s);`

Comment: @rufus...is that in c#

Comment: @Haywhy yes, why do you ask? Is it not working for you? Do you have a more specific question?

Comment: @rufus, have updated the question

Comment: The code I provided does what you want. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make 3 Lists:

```
static List<int> List1 = new List<int>();
static List<int> List2 = new List<int>();
static List<int> List3 = new List<int>();


void Sample()
    {
        List1.Add(2);
        List2.Add(3);

        for(int i=0;i<List1.Count();i++)
        {
            List3.Add(List1[i] + List2[i]);
        }
    }
```

as a result you have summarized in List3

Comment: List<int> qtyNumbers = new List<int>();

Comment: @Haywhy This code also does what you've asked. Please narrow your question to something more specific if it hasn't been answered (except modifying `static` members in an `instance` class could prove problematic depending on the requirements).